# How to get screen width from within a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a view which contains several elements and which *can* get wider than the screen. Therefore I put it in a `HorizontalScrollView` :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" >

<view class="com.hb.examples.myapplication2.app.ui.controls.LineGraphView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/line_chart"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The containing View *can* get wider, but don't have to. When its smaller than the screen I want to be it as wide as possible without displaying the Scrollbar. So how do I get the Screenwidth to return in to Android via `setMeasuredDimension` in `onMeasure`?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to do anything to achieve this behaviour as it is its default one. You put a `ScrollView` (an horizontal in this case) to `match_parent` and it will match the screen (as long as it is the root view of course), and if it's children makes it wider, it will automatically adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a view, you can retrieve [display metrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) from the context the view is associated with

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
setMeasuredDimension(metrics.widthPixels, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I take parents (fragment, HorizontalScrollView) padding into account?